# onClick not working on first click in react nested component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component. This parent component combines a lot of if else control and a lot of mini jsx. I added my case. If I click the NextBtnText in the Modal component. It doesn't fire the first click. It needs a second click.
How can I fire the first click? What is wrong?

```
const StepperComponent = ({closeModal}) => {
      
      /**
       * there is some ,useState, useEffect and conditional functions
      */

      const test = () => setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
    
      const NextBtnText = () => {
        return (<Button
            onClick={test}
            disabled={firmType}
            className={styles.StepperNextButton}
          >
            <span>{t("createFirm.buttons.next")}</span>
            <KeyboardArrowRightIcon />
          </Button>
        );
      };
    
      const BackBtnText = () => {
        return (
          <>
            <span>{t("createFirm.buttons.back")}</span>
          </>
        );
      }
    
      
      const RequestAssignmentBtnText = () => {
        return (
          <Button
            onClick={handleSubmit}
            disabled={firmType}
            className={styles.StepperRequestButton}
          >
            <span>{t("createFirm.buttons.requestAssignment")}</span>
          </Button>
        )
      }
    
      return (
        <div className={styles.StepperContainer}>
          <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} className={styles.Steps}>
            {steps.map((label, index) => {
              return (
                <Step key={index}>
                  <StepLabel >{label}<span className={styles.StepCountMobile}>{`(${index + 1} / ${steps.length})`}</span></StepLabel>
                </Step>
              );
            })}
          </Stepper>
          {getStepContent(activeStep)}
          <div className={styles.StepperButtons}>
            <Button
              disabled={activeStep === 0}
              onClick={handleBack}
              className={styles.StepperBackButton}
            >
              <span>{t("createFirm.buttons.back")}</span>
            </Button>
            {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? (<RequestAssignmentBtnText />) : (<NextBtnText />)}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo're not calling your function. Simply do:

```
<Button
onClick={(event) => handleSubmit(event)}
>

// Your function has to look like this

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  // your code...
}
```

Or you can do this:

```
<Button
onClick={handleSubmit()}
>

// Your function has to look like this

const handleSubmit = () => {
   return (event) => {
     // your code...
   }
}
```

Comment: `onClick={handleSubmit()}` should be `onClick={handleSubmit}`.

Comment: Nope, it's correct if your function looks like the one I posted

Comment: @ask4you, you don't want to execute a function inside of the event handler

Comment: I edited the test function like this :
 const test = () => setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
or 
const test = (e) => console.log('test', e.target)
But doesn't matter. It doesn't work the first time.

Comment: Ok, then `onClick={() => handleSubmit()}` won't work as intended assuming you're using the same `handleClick` function for both examples.

Comment: @ht13 but the problem is with your `handleSubmit` function or the `test` function? or both? Can you update and post the `handleSubmit` function and the `activeStep` state?

Comment: @ask4you I don't have the handleSumbit function. I never added handleFunction. The problem is the test function.

Comment: Test function continue next step

Comment: did you try checking if the value for `activeStep` is getting updated by doing a `console.log(activeStep)` before the `return` statement?

Comment: I checked, also I checked in the function. It changed then the second click.

Answer (score 0):

What is the default value you set in `useState()` for `activeStep`?

I believe the `onClick` handler is working but the state is not what you expect on the first click. Maybe set the default value to `1` or `0` (I am not sure what is suitable for your use case).

```js
const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(1);
```

If the `onClick` is actually not working with the first click, try using plain HTML `<input />` with `test` `onClick` handler and see if that works. It might have something to do with the `Button` component itself.

Comment: I set const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);

Comment: onClick doesn't work first time. I controlled debugging.

Comment: Try replacing `Button` component with a plain HTML `<button />` input and see if that works with first click.

Comment: It's the same. The next button has a disabled so disabled={firmType}. In the first time the firmType is false. User select something it'll be true. and so onclick will fire. Is the disable attr broke onClick?

Comment: Yeah, remove `disabled` for now and test. If it works as expected without `disabled` prop, you can narrow down your investigation to `firmType`.

Comment: I found the problem. My component is in the Modal. And I have two checkbox. According to checkbox state, Next btn can be disable or enable. I pick one checkbox, and it render  next button component for disable/enable attrs. If I click anywhere in the modal,  render will complete, this is problem. How to fix the render problem?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the onClick problem. The cause is about rerendered after disabled={firmType}. My button has a disabled attribute. I need to control after the checkbox is true/false.

Before :

```
{activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? (<RequestAssignmentBtnText />) : (<NextBtnText />)}
```

Solution :

```
{activeStep === steps.length - 1
          ?
          <Button
            onClick={handleSubmit}
            className={styles.StepperNextButton}
          >
            <span>{t("createFirm.buttons.requestAssignment")}</span>
          </Button>
          :
          <Button
            onClick={handleNext}
            disabled={firmType}
            className={styles.StepperNextButton}
          >
            <span>{t("createFirm.buttons.next")}</span>
            <KeyboardArrowRightIcon />
          </Button>
        }
```

Actually, I want to know what is different between Before and Solution.

Maybe someone can explain the issue of solution.